# Solution Explorer's "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" equivalent for "Solution Navigator"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer, productivity-power-tools

By default, VS2010 will track the current file you are editing in Solution Explorer.
if not, the feature can be enabled from:

*VS2010 menus > Options > Projects and solutions > "**Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**"*

This means the active tab is highlighted in the Solution Explorer and makes the programmers job easier to find the active file in the big projects.

However, for the people who installed [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/?SRC=VSIDE) and using **Solution Navigator** the trick above wont' work.

Any tools or options which can do the same for Solution Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution Explorer Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ef4ac3e9-d056-4383-8ca2-11721bd879b4) does the job. It's not as practical as ***"Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"*** and needs the Sync button, added to Solution Navigator, to be pressed or a shortcut to be set.

Would like to hear better solutions if available.